# I want to add two columns names to an existing table in Impala Query

Tags: impala

I am writing the following query to add a column at a specified position but getting the below error:

```
alter table quantum_raw_dev.rpt_backup_allocation
change upt_type upt_type STRING after tray_size;
```

Comment: You added your query, but forgot to add your error. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61520980/edit). Don't forget to check if the specific SQL syntax you are using is supported by the database you are using. Show us a link to the documentation if you like. If necessary tell us what version of Impala you are using.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding or Removing Columns**

You can add one or more columns to the end of the column list using `ADD COLUMNS`,
or (with `Impala` only) you can delete columns using `DROP COLUMN`.
The general syntax is

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMNS (col1 TYPE1,col2 TYPE2,… );

ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN colname;
```

For example, you can add a bonus integer column to the employees table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employees ADD COLUMNS (bonus INT);
```

Or you can drop the `office_id` column from the employees table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employees DROP COLUMN office_id;
```

**Notes**

`DROP COLUMN` is not available in `Hive`, only in `Impala`. However, see ***“Replacing All Columns”*** below.

You can only `drop` one column at a time.
To `drop` multiple columns, use multiple statements or use the method to `replace` columns (see below).

You cannot `add` a column in the middle of the list rather than at the end.
You can, however, `add` the column then change the order (see above) or use the method to `replace` columns (see below).

As with changing the column order, these do not change the data files.

If the table definition agrees with the data files before you `drop` any column other than the last one,
you will need to recreate the data files without the dropped column's values.
If you `drop` the last column, the data will still exist but it will be ignored when a query is issued.
If you `add` columns for which no data exists, those columns will be `NULL` in each row.

**Replacing All Columns**

You can also completely `replace` all the columns with a new column list.
This is helpful for dropping multiple columns,

```html
<h1>or if you need to add columns in the middle of the list<h1>
<h2>(like your use case)<h2>
```

**The general syntax is**

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename REPLACE COLUMNS (col1 TYPE1,col2 TYPE2,… );
```

This completely removes the existing list of columns and replaces it with the new list.
Only the columns you specify in the `ALTER TABLE` statement will exist, and they will be in the order you provide.

**Note**

Again, this does not change the data files, only the metadata for the table,
so you'll either want the new list to match the data files or need to recreate the data files to match the new list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one or more columns to the end of the column list using:

ALTER TABLE <*table_name*> ADD COLUMNS (*col_name* *col_type*, ...);

[note: there is NO comma between column name and type]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add column in between. Best way is to archive the data in another table. Drop the impala old table and create a fresh table with new columns as per the desired location and then reinsert the data.

Why we must create a fresh table first? Couldn't we insert into the existing table?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can add columns in between columns in Impala like above.
You can backup the data, drop the and recreate with new structure, and load the table from backup. Also if you have HIVE in your system you can try to do below steps -
Add column first and then use below commands to move columns around.
    `ALTER TABLE tab ADD COLUMNS (id BIGINT);`
 This moves id column to the beginning.
`ALTER TABLE tab CHANGE COLUMN id id BIGINT first;`
This moves existing_col after id.
`ALTER TABLE tab CHANGE COLUMN existing_col existing_col string AFTER id;`

Please refresh/invalidate metadata after applying all DDLs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add column in between. Best way is to archive the data in another table. Drop the impala old table and create a fresh table with new columns as per the desired location and then reinsert the data.